# GeoJsonLayer Change feature style on setOnFeatureClickListener

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, geojson

Hello I'm implementing Google Maps android using maps-utils. I have added a **GeoJsonLayer**(LineString) now i want to change the feature style(color & width) after user clicks on a feature of the GeoJsonLayer. So far i didn't find any property that related to feature style.

```
road_layer=new GeoJsonLayer(mMap,R.raw.road_survey,this);
road_layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new   Layer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {

              //implement feature related operations 

            }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well after reading the Google Maps Android GeoJSON Utility documentation briefly i manage to achieve my goal

```
road_layer=new GeoJsonLayer(mMap,R.raw.road_survey,this);
road_layer.setOnFeatureClickListener(new   Layer.OnFeatureClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFeatureClick(Feature feature) {
          GeoJsonLineStringStyle lineStringStyle = new GeoJsonLineStringStyle();
          lineStringFeature = (GeoJsonFeature) feature;
          lineStringStyle.setColor(Color.RED);
          lineStringStyle.setZIndex(10f);
          lineStringStyle.setWidth(2f);
          lineStringFeature.setLineStringStyle(lineStringStyle);

        }
});
```

Comment: This is useful only if we want to update solid colors for lines or polygons, as it will not remove the previous layer of color but add on top of that. Therefore, if we add alpha, it will get darker with each update. Is there any approach to update or clear the last updated color?